# Can I use Google Polymer from a standard Javascript app?

Tags: javascript, dart, polymer

I saw  on the google blog that Google Polymer has a dart version called polymer.dart, so this confused me a bit, as I thought it was just one set of components.

Comment: Why the closing vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a port. Have a look here (the first google hit, so that's probably why the closing vote.)

http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html